# Validity of immediate functions

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

While testing some of the features of immediate functions, I noticed some discrepancies between the produced results of some of the mainstream C++ compilers (Clang 15, GCC 12.2, MSVC 19.33). Taking the rules of [core constant expressions](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.const#def:expression,core_constant) into consideration, my expectation would be that all of the following snippets of code produce an error on each of the tested compilers. To my surprise, there seems to be a lot of disagreement about which of the immediate functions is considered to be valid.

Should all compilers produce errors for all of the presented test cases? Or, should some of them instead be rergarded as well-formed?

[Code examples](https://godbolt.org/z/M8MYTTxYq):

```
// #1 | clang: error | gcc: ok | msvc: error
[]() consteval { int i; +i; }();

// #3 | clang: error | gcc: ok | msvc: error
[]() consteval { 1 / 0; }();

// #4 | clang: error | gcc: ok | msvc: error
[]() consteval { 1 << -1; }();

// #5 | clang: error | gcc: ok | msvc: error
[]() consteval { 1 >> -1; }();

// #6 | clang: error | gcc: ok | msvc: ok
[]() consteval { static_assert(sizeof(int) == 4); -(1 << 31); }();

// #7 | clang: error | gcc: ok | msvc: error
[]() consteval { union { int i; } u; +u.i; }();

// #8 | clang: error | gcc: ok | msvc: error
[]() consteval { union { bool b; int i; } u{}; +u.i; }();

// #9 | clang: error | gcc: ok | msvc: error
[]() consteval { int a[1]; +a[1]; }();

// #10 | clang: error | gcc: ok | msvc: error
[]() consteval { int* p; +*p; }();

// #16 | clang: error | gcc: ok | msvc: error
[]() consteval { auto p = new int; delete p; +*p; }();

// #17 | clang: error | gcc: ok | msvc: error
[]() consteval { int* p; { int i; p = &i; } +*p; }();

// #18 | clang: error | gcc: error | msvc: ok
[]() consteval { int const c{}; const_cast<int&>(c) = 0; }();

// #19 | clang: error | gcc: ok | msvc: error
[]() consteval { +*static_cast<int*>(nullptr); }();

// #20 | clang: error | gcc: ok | msvc: ok
[]() consteval { static_cast<int*>(static_cast<void*>(nullptr)); }();

// #21 | clang: ok | gcc: error | msvc: error
[]() consteval { *static_cast<void*>(nullptr); }();

// #22 | clang: error | gcc: error | msvc: ok
[]() consteval { reinterpret_cast<void*>(nullptr); }();
```

Overview of test results:

```
Test | Clang | GCC   | MSVC
-----+-------+-------+--------
  #1 | error | ok    | error
  #3 | error | ok    | error
  #4 | error | ok    | error
  #5 | error | ok    | error
  #6 | error | ok    | ok
  #7 | error | ok    | error
  #8 | error | ok    | error
  #9 | error | ok    | error
 #10 | error | ok    | error
 #16 | error | ok    | error
 #17 | error | ok    | error
 #18 | error | error | ok
 #19 | error | ok    | error
 #20 | error | ok    | ok
 #21 | ok    | error | error
 #22 | error | error | ok
```

Comment: "*`static_cast<int*>(static_cast<void*>(nullptr));`*" Is that supposed to be UB? Because it isn't.

Comment: It seems pretty clear that GCC is optimizing away any code that does not lead to something which gets returned.

Comment: This also has nothing to do with `consteval`, as all of these happen if you make the functions `constexpr` (and force their use in constant evaluation by assigning the return values to a `constexpr` variable).

Comment: @NicolBolas Well, isn't `reinterpret_cast<T*>(ptr)` specified to behave exactly the same as `static_cast<T*>(static_cast<void*>(ptr))`? Since the former is not allowed in compile time, I can see why a compiler doesn't allow the latter either.

Comment: @NicolBolas Alright, but it is not clear to me if those functions should be regarderd as well-formed. In this case, I also can see why a compiler would reject a statement such as `1 / 0;` in a compile time function.

Comment: @NicolBolas Maybe I shouldn't have put that much emphasis on immediate functions but they do come in handy since some of the expressions that I've tested do not return any values.

Comment: @303, `reinterpret_cast` is specially marked as one of the things that isn't allowed in a constant expression. The behaviour can be identical while still having only one of them marked as such (which bans the entire construct, not just the equivalent case). In fairness, though, a `void*` to `object*` conversion is listed right above that.

Comment: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.constexpr#6